# Regex to match exactly a word

Tags: regex

So im looking to get a regex to find exactly some words and not all word that contain that word
My regex looks like this

```
"^.*?(java.*|test.*|dev.*).*$"
```

At this moment:

- javascript : matches     - should NOT match
- tester : matches      - should NOT match
- Im a dev : should match

I want to make it so that only exactly these words"java,test,dev" are matched and not every word that contains these words.

Comment: What flavor of regex?

Comment: im using android studio to develop a java app. java.util.regex

Comment: what wrong with @on8tom answer ?

Answer (score 0):

For PCRE you can use word boundaries

```
\b(java|test|dev)\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/URxffV/1

Comment: Thank you for your answer but im not able to use PCRE.

Comment: then what version are you using?